# In rails error is as NameError in ProductsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have written a controller and model to get data from db. But it shows the error when we run rails is:NameError in ProductsController#index  in the url.. i give my url as localhost:3000/products. then it is giving error as:

```
 NameError in ProductsController#index

    uninitialized constant ProductsController::Product.


    my controller is:
    products_controller.rb
    class ProductsController < ApplicationController
      # GET /products
      # GET /products.json

      def index
        @products = Product.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @products }
        end
      end

      #render :text => params and return false
      # GET /products/PR1
      # GET /products/PR1.json
      def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:prod_id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @product }
        end
      end

    end

    model as product.rb
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :model_name, :brand_name, :price, :discount, :qty_available
    end
```

i declared in routes.rb as:
resources :products

and i designed index.html.erb and show.html.erb

I dont know where the error is really...

Comment: Do you have a model named product.rb in app/models/ directory?

Comment: It's `product.rb`, not `products.rb`.

Comment: frnds.. both of u r right.. i named the model as products.rb but it should be as product.rb.. but now the error is template missing.. what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model name is `product.rb` and not `products.rb` and in your show action, you want a single product so the correct syntax is :

```
    def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @product }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. but now the problem is it is not connecting to the html pages. it simply shows json data on the browser. the error is ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#show

Comment: Are you calling `@product` instead of `@products` in the show view ?

Comment: @product = Product.find(params[:prod_id])

Comment: Not in the controller, I am talking about the view. And did you try `params[:id]` instead of `params[:prod_id]`

Comment: I have a doubt..in db, the primary key is prod_id.. then how can i call only id??

Comment: If your primary key is prod_id, you then have to call prod_id, but in the show.html.erb, you have to call the instance variable you defined in the show action of your controller, that is to say `@product`.

Comment: ok.. I tried with @product also.. but it shows error as:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ProductsController#show

PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...T  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."" = $1 LI...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21012/discussion-between-pavankumar-and-siekfried)

Answer (score 0):

use find_by_id instead of find. it throws exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound whenever record is not found and where as find_by_id returns you nil

Comment: if i use find_by_id instead of find(params[id]),it returns NoMethodError in ProductsController#show undefined method `find_by_id' for #<Class:0xb73769d4>